# How to assign colour to each countries based on a given set of values

Tags: google-visualization

i have to create a GeoChart of US region. currently the color assign to each countries depends on colorAxis.color in a gradient . is there any way to specify color to each country based on given range of values. For example:
value between 0-20 to have Red color
value between 21-40 to have yellow color 
and son on? any help in this issue is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the gradient could be overridden if a color name is supplied for every value, using...

```
  colorAxis: {
    colors: colorNames,  // array of color names -- one for each value
    values: colorValues  // array of values extracted from the data and sorted ascending
  },
```

here, I adjust the range to match up with the data from a GeoChart example...
`red <= -10 > yellow <= 10 > green`

```js
google.charts.load('44', {'packages':['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var dataRows = [
    ['Country',   'Latitude'],
    ['Algeria', 36], ['Angola', -8], ['Benin', 6], ['Botswana', -24],
    ['Burkina Faso', 12], ['Burundi', -3], ['Cameroon', 3],
    ['Canary Islands', 28], ['Cape Verde', 15],
    ['Central African Republic', 4], ['Ceuta', 35], ['Chad', 12],
    ['Comoros', -12], ['Cote d\'Ivoire', 6],
    ['Democratic Republic of the Congo', -3], ['Djibouti', 12],
    ['Egypt', 26], ['Equatorial Guinea', 3], ['Eritrea', 15],
    ['Ethiopia', 9], ['Gabon', 0], ['Gambia', 13], ['Ghana', 5],
    ['Guinea', 10], ['Guinea-Bissau', 12], ['Kenya', -1],
    ['Lesotho', -29], ['Liberia', 6], ['Libya', 32], ['Madagascar', 13],
    ['Madeira', 33], ['Malawi', -14], ['Mali', 12], ['Mauritania', 18],
    ['Mauritius', -20], ['Mayotte', -13], ['Melilla', 35],
    ['Morocco', 32], ['Mozambique', -25], ['Namibia', -22],
    ['Niger', 14], ['Nigeria', 8], ['Republic of the Congo', -1],
    ['Réunion', -21], ['Rwanda', -2], ['Saint Helena', -16],
    ['São Tomé and Principe', 0], ['Senegal', 15],
    ['Seychelles', -5], ['Sierra Leone', 8], ['Somalia', 2],
    ['Sudan', 15], ['South Africa', -30], ['South Sudan', 5],
    ['Swaziland', -26], ['Tanzania', -6], ['Togo', 6], ['Tunisia', 34],
    ['Uganda', 1], ['Western Sahara', 25], ['Zambia', -15],
    ['Zimbabwe', -18]
  ];

  // extract column index 1 for color values
  var colorValues = dataRows.map(function(val){
      return val.slice(-1);
  });
  // remove column label
  colorValues.splice(0, 1);
  // sort ascending
  colorValues.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

  // build color names red <= -10 > yellow <= 10 > green
  var colorNames = [];
  colorValues.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value <= -10) {
      colorNames.push('red');
    } else if ((value > -10) && (value <= 10)) {
      colorNames.push('yellow');
    } else {
      colorNames.push('green');
    }
  });

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRows);

  var options = {
    region: '002',
    colorAxis: {
      colors: colorNames,
      values: colorValues
    },
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 700px; height: 433px;"></div>
```

Comment: you were right about passing a color  to each value. i solved this by adding an extra parameter which defines it color and adding it to the colorAxis.values. thanks a lot for the help.